# Tell docker to use the DNS server in the host system

Tags: ubuntu, dns, docker, dnsmasq

I have `dnsmasq` running in the host, and I want the docker containers to use that, instead of the [default Google servers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) (`8.8.8.8`)

My host `/etc/resolv.conf` looks as follows:

```
» cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search mydomain.net
```

And the container's `/etc/resolv.conf` looks as follows:

```
root@ubuntu:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
search mydomain.net

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

It seems that docker is reusing the host's `/etc/resolv.conf` but discarding the `127.0.0.1` entry, and instead adding Google's nameservers.

I have tried adding a dns entry referring to the `docker0` interface:

```
» ifconfig docker0
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8e:65:b0:88  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:8eff:fe65:b088/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:55824 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:74365 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15702804 (15.7 MB)  TX bytes:60639605 (60.6 MB)
```

As follows:

```
docker run \
    -it \
    --name ubuntu.bionic \
    --restart always \
    --dns 172.17.0.1 \
    ubuntu:bionic
```

But dns is not working:

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
```

How can I dell a docker container to use the dns server in the host system?

### EDIT

It seems that I need to tell `dnsmasq` to bind to the `docker0` interface:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1,172.17.0.1
```

I still do not like that I need to give the IP address of the `docker0` interface *twice*, once for the `docker run` command for **each container** that I want to create, and also for the `dnsmasq` configuration.

### EDIT2

I can tell `docker` to use by default my local DNS server (which is runninng in a container, and reachable to the other containers in the `docker0` interface: `172.17.0.1`):

```
» sudo cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
    "dns": ["172.17.0.1", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

And then restart the docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

I am still somewhat worried that `docker` could decide to change the IP address of the `docker0` interface, and I will be forced to reconfigure `docker` and `dnsmasq`, and rebuild the containers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the host's local DNS resolver (e.g. `dnsmasq`) from your Docker containers if they are on a [**user defined network**](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/1654). In that case a container's `/etc/resolv.conf` will have the nameserver `127.0.0.11` (a.k.a. the Docker's [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)), which can forward DNS requests to the host's loopback address properly.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
$ docker run --rm alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
$ docker network create demo
557079c79ddf6be7d6def935fa0c1c3c8290a0db4649c4679b84f6363e3dd9a0
$ docker run --rm --net demo alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

If you use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), it will set up a custom network for your services automatically (with a file format [v2+](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-2)). Note, however, that while `docker-compose` runs containers in a user-defined network, it still builds them in the **default network**. To use a custom network for builds you can specify  the `network` parameter in the [build configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build) (requires file format [v3.4+](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#version-34)).